# How long should I wait before redesigning a website?

Tags: website-design, user-engagement

I am the webmaster of a local news website which is online for 6 months now and I considered redesigning it. The website is running on a Wordpress CMS, so all I had to do is to apply a new theme. But instead, I just tweaked fonts, text sizes and color schemes for more reading comfort.

Why tweaking instead of redesigning ? Because I thought that it may be *harmful* to user-engagement if readers would have to rediscover the site all over again, only 6 months after it's launch (not to mention all the work just to put everything in order again).

Does redesigning a website frequently good or bad ? How long should I wait before redesigning the site (regardless of platform and content types) ?

Comment: Subjective questions like this are better left for [chat].

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess this would go on to how the users adapt to your website.
I would not recommend regular redesigns because, as you said, people would have to rediscover the site every time and specially in a news website I would guess your demographics are mostly conservative people who like certain things to remain constant.

That being said, it should also be pointed out that trends change and sometimes a website should be brought up-to-date. I would not recommend a update (unless the "game" changes completely all the sudden) before 1-1,5 year, but keep informing yourself on trends and what is happening in the field where your website works ("media" in your case)
In between you should work on tweaking the website and getting a better user experience. Maybe do some minor pools (if you have control over the content) on what the users think of the site and what they think could be improved.

Remember the users must be satisfied and their feedback is one of your greatest tools. (just don't go changing everything they want, it is impossible to make everyone happy anyway ;) ) Make sure they are happy and you have got a good website :)

In a a more technical point of view, if you redesign your website and the structure changes (not only the look) make sure you make 301 redirects so you do not lose your traffic or ranking on search tools.